# Session object is throwing exception in a WebService

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I am trying to store a url in Session object but it is throwing an error.

```
      Session["Url"]= linkDetails.Url;
```

the Url value is shown to be

```
             http://www.mnn.com/earth-matters/space/photos/10-places-on-earth-that-resemble-alien-planets/etosha-pan-namibia
```

the exception is

```
  Object reference is not set an instance of the object
```

Comment: Check if `linkDetails` is null

Comment: no it is not null.. the value is shown up there

Comment: Has the Session object been initialised yet? Where are you accessing it? In Global.asax or something like that?

Comment: It is a webservice... :o

Comment: then you have to enableSession for it

Comment: Use [WebMethod(EnableSession=true)]

Comment: oh... sh.... I totlly forgot.. Thanks

Comment: put this in an answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use web service, you have to enable session for it.

Try `[WebMethod(EnableSession=true)]`